# How to pass arguments from seeders to factories?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to pass arguments `['site_id' => $site->id]` to SiteMessage factory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\SiteMessage;
use App\Models\Site;

class SitesMessagesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function run()
    {
        Site::chunk(200, function ($sites) {
            foreach ($sites as $site) {
                SiteMessage::factory()->count(rand(2, 6))->create(['site_id' => $site->id]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I get those argument in my SiteMessage factory class?

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\SiteMessage;
use App\Models\Site;
use App\Models\Integration;

class SiteMessageFactory extends Factory
{
   
    protected $model = SiteMessage::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
             **// Soliution: remove line below, it will be overridden automaticaly. \\**
            'site_id'       => $arguments['site_id'], // Neet to use Id that I passed from seeder. 
            'integration_id'=> Integration::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'type'          => rand(0,1) ? 'EMAIL' : 'SMS',
            'title'         => $this->faker->text($maxNbChars = 12),
            'description'   => $this->faker->sentence,
            'message'       => $this->faker->sentence,
            'enabled'       => 1,
            'created_at'    => now(),
            'updated_at'    => now(),
        ];
    }
}
```

At older Laravel factory version I could pass them in callback like so:

```
$factory->define(SiteMessage::class, function (Faker $faker, array $arguments = []) {
//
});
```

but don't know how to achieve it with new Class factories. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the laravel documentation about [persisting models with factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#persisting-models),  when you type:

```
SiteMessage::factory()->count(rand(2, 6))->create(['site_id' => $site->id]);
```

The site_id attribute from SiteMessage factory will be overrided by the `$site->id` you are specifying.